# How do I cancel JPA update operation based on logic in perUpdate event?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entitylisteners

I need to cancel JPA merge operation based on some logic inside `@PreUpdate` listener method like:

```
@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate(BaseEntity entity) throws Exception {
    if (!entity.isModified()) {
        EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        //cancel update operation on this entity only 
        //and keep update to its children
    }
}
```

cancel/exclude this entity from update operation and keeping the other associated entities eligible for update (i.e when using `CascadeType.MERGE`)

Comment: you could fetch the main entity fresh in another instance, copy the updated stuff you want to persist from the preupdate argument, and merge

Comment: my problem is that I don't want to update the entity unless its direct attributes been really modified ... the code is using a lot of merge and cascade merge