# How do I update operation based on logic in perUpdate event

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want Hibernate PostUpdateEventListener callback onPostUpdate() method to invoke conditionally. I am trying to achieve this by writing some logic in the hibernate  lifecycle callback method onPreUpdate() method of PreUpdateEventListener , so that it will check a specific condition and stop further update processing & execution of onPostUpdate() if the condition evaluates to false.

Is there any significance of returning true or false value from onPreUpdate method to stop further update processing and execution of onPostUpdate() method. I already tried to return true as well as false from preUpdate() but there is no impact i.e. in both cases update processing is being performed & postUpdate() method invocation is being done.

Details : It is checker maker requirement.My requirement is to log some specific set of entities in Database to mark them as checked along with the data of update request if the user role is "Maker" and only do updates call in DB if user is of type "Checker". Therefore I need to prevent update processing if the user role is maker and log them as "Checked" and update through "Checker" user role.

Comment: what kind of "condition"?

Comment: I am accessing a specific attribute from HttpRequest object and on basis of that attribute, i've to perform some updates to DB for few entities. This has to be apply on all PUT services for those entities, so I decided to check attribute in the preUpdate() method and if the condition evaluates to true then continue the PUT services execution otherwise stop to process the PUT operation as well as postUpdate()

Comment: and what exactly is the problem? your description is rather unclear

Comment: It is checker maker requirement.My requirement is to log some specific set of entities in DB  to mark them as checked with the data of update request if the user role is "Maker" and only do updates call in DB if user is of type "Checker". Therefore I need to prevent update processing if the user role is maker.

Comment: The similar question was posted 3 years ago but still it is unanswerable...My question is duplicate of the following thread :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577200/how-do-i-cancel-jpa-update-operation-based-on-logic-in-perupdate-event